# Casting initializers down to a pointer

Tags: c, casting, initialization

Why doesn't this work? Is it possible to do some creative casting to get this to work?

```
1: const char* yo1 = "abc";
2: const char* yo2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }; // <-- why can't i do this?
3: printf("%s %s\n", yo1, yo2);
```

Result: Segmentation Fault

Line 2 isn't doing what I expect it to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
const char* yo2 = (char [4]) { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
```

which is valid and will achieve what you want. Note that it is not equivalent to:

```
const char* yo2 = "abc":
```

In the former case, when `yo2` is declared at file-scope: the compound literal array has static storage duration but when `yo2` is declared at block-scope the compound literal has automatic storage duration.

In the latter case, `"abc"` is a string literal and has static storage duration (file scope or block scope).

You can also use an array instead of a pointer:

```
 const char yo2[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
```

Regarding your example. In C:

```
const char* yo2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
```

is not valid and your compiler interprets it as:

```
const char* yo2 = (char *) 'a';
```

The value of `'a'` is not a pointer value (an address) so dereferencing `yo2` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: No! The RHS is a temporary; it's not guaranteed to stick around.

Comment: @nneonneo it's a compound literal. It has automatic storage duration if declared at block scope. Now why the downvote please?

Comment: In C, yes. But this becomes unsafe as soon as you use it in C++, or compile it in C++ mode. So it is not a safe practice in my books.

Comment: @nneonneo the question is tagged C so I answer it for C. C and C++ are two different languages.